# Homogenous Systems Question

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

$A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$

If $I - B$ is singular, then $\exists x$ from $\mathbb{C}^n$  so that $(I - B)x = 0$.

How do I show that $|| B || \geq 1$ and if $|| A || \leq 1$ then $I-A$ isn't singular?

It's not really clear for me either, but I think the norm I'm supposed to use is $ || A || = \max \{ | a_{ij} | \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement should be:

> if $\|A\|\color{red}{<}1$, then $I-A$ is nonsingular.

The usual proof is to show that the power series $I+A+A^2+\ldots$ converges (we need $\|A\|<1$ here) and it is the inverse of $I-A$. Which norm you are using is irrelevant, as long as the norm is a submultiplicative matrix norm.

Your statement for $B$ is just the contrapositive of the statement in the grey box.

Comment: Indeed, if you take A = I then I - A is singular and the statement is false.  Also, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If i'm not asking for much, could you please elaborate on the solution assuming || A || < 1. I have to reach to (I-A)^(-1) = I + A(I-A)^(-1) and I guess working with the power series should somehow get me there but I'm having issues. Thank you!

Comment: @byte1918 $I+A+A^2+\ldots$ converges because the radius of convergence of the power series $1+x+x^2+\ldots$ is $1$. Alternatively, when $\|A\|<1$, the sequence $B_n=\sum_{k=0}^nA^n$ is a Cauchy sequence (in fact, when $m,n\ge N$, we have $\|B_m-B_n\|\le\sum_{k=N}^\infty\|A\|^k=\frac{\|A\|^N}{1-\|A\|}$). Therefore $I+A+A^2+\ldots$ converges. Now you may directly verify that $(I-A)(I+A+A^2+\ldots)=I$ and hence the two bracketed terms are inverses to each other.

Comment: Thanks @user1551, with this explanation you actually helped me solve another part of my exercise. I, very much, appreciate your help!